# how to covert json string to byte array in java

Tags: java, json, string

```
String json="{"FROM_JID":"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701","TO_JID":"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1","TYPE_ID":"1","PLATFORM":"IOS","CONTENT":"{\"FROM_JID\":\"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701\",\"FROM_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"FROM_JNAME\":\"test1\",\"TO_JID\":\"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1\",\"TO_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"MESSAGE_ID\":\"LiYaU-39\",\"MESSAGE_TYPE\":\"enc\",\"MESSAGE\":\"test1 has sent you an encrypted message.\",\"STAMP\":\"2015-11-12 12:04:54.252241\",\"BADGE\":3,\"CONTENT-AVAILABLE\":1,\"SOUND\":\"dafault\"}","DEVICE_ID":"AC53D4F0-DAAA-475E-9668-5E9E7485797C","PUSH_ID":"c9544c8db2117f02f3edc8af9058b3d54c15500302bf6f47c487193876f6dc23","CREATE_DATE":"2015-11-12","CREATE_TIME":"04:04:54"}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
```

but it showing error

Comment: I recommend before touching JSON, go back to java syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, this won't compile:

```
String json="{"FROM_JID":"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701","TO_JID":"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1","TYPE_ID":"1","PLATFORM":"IOS","CONTENT":"{\"FROM_JID\":\"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701\",\"FROM_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"FROM_JNAME\":\"test1\",\"TO_JID\":\"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1\",\"TO_HOST\":\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\",\"MESSAGE_ID\":\"LiYaU-39\",\"MESSAGE_TYPE\":\"enc\",\"MESSAGE\":\"test1 has sent you an encrypted message.\",\"STAMP\":\"2015-11-12 12:04:54.252241\",\"BADGE\":3,\"CONTENT-AVAILABLE\":1,\"SOUND\":\"dafault\"}","DEVICE_ID":"AC53D4F0-DAAA-475E-9668-5E9E7485797C","PUSH_ID":"c9544c8db2117f02f3edc8af9058b3d54c15500302bf6f47c487193876f6dc23","CREATE_DATE":"2015-11-12","CREATE_TIME":"04:04:54"}";
```

You even can notice that its syntax is not highlighted properly.

You need [to escape your quotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in order to make Java recognize it as a part of a string, but not your code:

```
String json="{\"FROM_JID\":\"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701\",\"TO_JID\":\"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1\",\"TYPE_ID\":\"1\",\"PLATFORM\":\"IOS\",\"CONTENT\":\"{\\\"FROM_JID\\\":\\\"6bc24cac4eaf304ce1731bd5aebe9b0419052701\\\",\\\"FROM_HOST\\\":\\\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\\\",\\\"FROM_JNAME\\\":\\\"test1\\\",\\\"TO_JID\\\":\\\"dfc8d53f402373a1d3622dde50e180b388b36bc1\\\",\\\"TO_HOST\\\":\\\"ssdevim.mtouche-mobile.com\\\",\\\"MESSAGE_ID\\\":\\\"LiYaU-39\\\",\\\"MESSAGE_TYPE\\\":\\\"enc\\\",\\\"MESSAGE\\\":\\\"test1 has sent you an encrypted message.\\\",\\\"STAMP\\\":\\\"2015-11-12 12:04:54.252241\\\",\\\"BADGE\\\":3,\\\"CONTENT-AVAILABLE\\\":1,\\\"SOUND\\\":\\\"dafault\\\"}\",\"DEVICE_ID\":\"AC53D4F0-DAAA-475E-9668-5E9E7485797C\",\"PUSH_ID\":\"c9544c8db2117f02f3edc8af9058b3d54c15500302bf6f47c487193876f6dc23\",\"CREATE_DATE\":\"2015-11-12\",\"CREATE_TIME\":\"04:04:54\"}";
```

**Second,** if you already have a `String` and you want to convert it to `byte[]`, why do you deserialize it? Just convert it to `byte` array:

```
byte[] bytes = json.getBytes();
```

Comment: above string json if i validate through http://jsonlint.com/ its showing errors,its not a proper json format

Comment: @naveen Of course, you will have errors, if you paste a Java escaped string to Jsonlint. Please, read some documentation on characters escaping: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112731/what-does-backslash-escape-character-really-escape) or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). It is not about Java, but the principles are the same in *all* languages.

Comment: if i use above string with valid format i got theese errors                        Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (F) at position 151.
        at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
        at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)

Comment: @naveen Oh, you have a nested JSON object...Then, you need to escape a backslash as well. I have updated my answer.